# Finding out what was changed for an AD user at a specific date

Tags: powershell

I was curious if it's possible (using Powershell or other methods) to somehow find out what was changed for an AD user at a specific date or before some specified date.
The reason is that I need to know if one user was a member of an AD group before a date or when was the user added to that AD group etc.

Is this possible somehow? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might try this solution in powershell https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Monitor-Active-Directory-4c4e04c7 or AD DS Auditing: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731607%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I more or less found my answer from here:
[http://blogs.technet.com/b/ashleymcglone/archive/2012/10/17/ad-group-history-mystery-powershell-v3-repadmin.aspx](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ashleymcglone/archive/2012/10/17/ad-group-history-mystery-powershell-v3-repadmin.aspx)
and
[http://blogs.technet.com/b/ashleymcglone/archive/2014/10/29/microsoft-virtual-academy-using-powershell-for-active-directory.aspx](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ashleymcglone/archive/2014/10/29/microsoft-virtual-academy-using-powershell-for-active-directory.aspx)